# TestCase for multiple files

Tags: tosca

I created one TestCase which I want to use on multiple files in one folder. The TestCase is for each file the same. Is there a possibility to do that in the Execution Section?
If possible I want to see after every File if it was successful or not.

Thank you and best regards

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar use case where I have 1 test case executing several iterations from a file. Currently, I'm leveraging Tricentis TDM solution to store the data rather then pulling from a file(s). You can create multiple repositories to store data ie: SQL Lite, MS SQL and other source systems. Check out https://www.tricentis.com/products/automate-continuous-testing-tosca/test-data-management/